# Does fitting a sklearn Linear Regression classifier multiple times add data points or just replace them?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

```
X = np.array(df.drop([label], 1))
X_lately = X[-forecast_out:]
X = X[:-forecast_out]
df.dropna(inplace=True)
y = np.array(df[label])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

linReg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I've been fitting my linear regression classifier over and over again with data from different spreadsheets under the assumption that every time I fit the same model with a new spreadsheet, it is adding points and making the model more robust.

Was this assumption correct? Or am I just wiping the model every time I fit it?

If so, is there a way for me to fit my model multiple times for this 'cumulative' type effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear regression is a batch (aka. offline) training method, you can't add knowledge with new patterns. So, sklearn is re-fitting the whole model. The only way to add data is to append the new patterns to your original training `X, Y` matrices and re-fit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get started combining my thousands of dataframes!

Comment: Can you elaborate more about batch (offline)? What would be the opposite Deep Learning?

Comment: The opposite is "online learning" or "instance- based learning"

Answer (score 0):

You're almost certainly wiping your mode land starting from scratch. To do what you want, you need to append the additional data to the bottom of your data frame and re-fit using that.

Comment: Answers with "almost certainty" are less likely to get upvoted; they're better as comments. Once you have certainty, perhaps from a citation, the community tends to view that as a good answer.